# How can I get the number of bytes downloaded in WebBrowser component

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

I am using the system.windows.controls.webbrowser component, I need to display in a different component the amount of bytes downloaded from the moment the component was started, any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs.CurrentProgress property can be used to determine the number of bytes downloaded.

[Check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs event of your web control and use the current progress property to get the number of bytes downloaded...

Quick example...

```
public long progress = 0;

private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progress += e.CurrentProgress;
    textBox1.Text = progress.ToString();
}
```

**:)**

Comment: This component is in System.Windows.Forms, the web browser I am using is in System.Windows.Controls, this component does not have this event.